# Putting table in a theorem environment sends it to the very end of the document

Tags: tables, theorems, wrapfigure, wrap

I'd like to illustrate my `\begin{example} \lipsum[2] \end{example}` with a table yet adding the table to the environment sends it to the very end of the document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig, lipsum, amsthm, thmtools}
\declaretheorem[style=remark,name=Example]{example}
\begin{document}

\begin{example}

\begin{wraptable}{r}{5.5cm}
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
    \hline
    header-a & header-b \\ 
    1 & 2 \\ 
    3 & 4 \\  
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{wraptable} 

\lipsum[2]

\end{example}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

And this is how it looks like: 
[image: table]

Comment: That seems normal since theorem-like environments are based on a list environment and `wrapfig` isn't very list-friendly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a hack that uses the generic macros from the `insbox.tex` set. I define a `\InsertExampleR` command, that can insert (almost) any box on the right, and has 2 mandatory and 1 optional arguments: the mandatory arguments are the number of lines whose length remain unchanged and the box to be inserted. The optional argument is the number of supplementary lines to be shortened, in case the box height is not well calculated. It may be adapted to any theorem-like environment, but depends on the theorem label.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig, lipsum, amsthm, thmtools, caption, xcolor, makebox}
\declaretheorem[style=remark,name=Example]{example}
\input{insbox.tex}

\newcommand{\InsertExampleR}[3][]{%
\leavevmode\vspace*{-\baselineskip}
\InsertBoxR{#2}{\enspace#3}[#1]
\hspace*{-\parindent}\makebox*{\textit{Example} \theexample.$\:$}{}
}%

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\InsertBoxMargin[1]{\@InsertBoxMargin = #1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{example}
\InsertExampleR{0}{%
\begin{tabular}{cc}
 \hline
 header-a & header-b \\
 1 & 2 \\
 3 & 4 \\
 \hline
 \end{tabular}}
\lipsum[2]%
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

[image]